# Como utilizar um proxy para obter um IP estático para minha aplicação Node.js?

Tags: node.js, api, deploy, ip, proxy

Estou consumindo a API do Brawl Stars e, para ter acesso a ela, é necessário uma chave que é atrelada ao endereço IP. Até aí tudo bem, quando eu rodava meu aplicativo localmente. No entanto, quando faço o deploy, não tenho acesso a esse IP para colocar na chave. Já estou há alguns meses tentando resolver isso, já tentei literalmente de tudo e, depois de semanas de pesquisa sobre como resolver isso, me deparei com uma pessoa no GitHub que disse ter resolvido utilizando um proxy. Ele disponibilizou o código do proxy no repositório dele. No entanto, surge outro problema: nunca utilizei um proxy. Mas como é a única forma de fazer isso funcionar, estou me esforçando para entender como funciona, mas está sendo difícil encontrar informações sobre isso.

Minhas dúvidas são: como posso utilizar esse proxy para conseguir um IP estático para o meu site? Quando eu subir esse proxy no servidor, ele não irá ficar com o IP dinâmico? (Essa pergunta pode parecer meio boba, mas estou realmente perdido). Onde eu encontro o 'IP do proxy' para colocar na chave da API?

O repositório que eu citei é este: https://github.com/DEV-DIBSTER/Brawl-Stars-Proxy

Parte onde eu consumo o proxy(Exemplo)

```
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // Proxy URL http://localhost:8000
        const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:8000/v1/players/%232LY8J89CV", {
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Authorization": `Bearer ${apiKey}`,
            }
        });
        return res.json(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.response) {
            const statusCode = error.response.status;
            let errorMessage = "Unknown error";
            let errorDetail = {};

            if (statusCode === 403) {
                errorMessage = "Access denied. Verify your credentials or API token.";
            } else if (statusCode === 404) {
                errorMessage = "Resource not found.";
            } else if (statusCode === 429) {
                errorMessage = "Request has been limited due to excessive requests.";
            } else if (statusCode === 500) {
                errorMessage = "Internal server error.";
            } else if (statusCode === 503) {
                errorMessage = "Service temporarily unavailable due to maintenance.";
            }

            return res.status(statusCode).json({
                error: errorMessage,
                detail: error.response.data
            });
        } else {
            console.error("Error making request to Brawl Stars API:", error.message);
            return res.status(500).json({
                error: "Internal server error",
                detail: error.message
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Agradeço qualquer orientação ou sugestão para resolver essa questão.